# Table cross-chapter reference works fine but shows "??"

Tags: tables, cross-referencing

When I reference **a table in a posterior chapter** in my thesis, instead of the correct table number it puts `??`. However, **the link works correctly**, and the **table appears in the List of Tables fine**.

I reference it as:

`\ref{tab:datasets}`

The table is:

`\begin{table}[h]
\label{tab:datasets}
...`

The log shows

`Reference 'tab:datasets' on page 16 undefined`

How can I make Latex show the proper table number?

Comment: Put the label behind the caption.

Comment: And you need to compile at least twice. The label number is written to the `.aux` file and read at the beginning (`\begin{document}`) of the next LaTeX run.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: As the table appears in the list of table and links work I think one can assume that the document has been compiled twice.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That does not explain the question marks. The `\label` could be added at a later time, the the auxiliary files already contain the caption, but not yet the label.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer gave the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run the program twice, one after another.
And before that, be sure you have used the standard `\label`-`\ref` system: `\label{labelname}` and `\ref{labelname}`. In your case `\label{tab:datasets}` and `\ref{tab:datasets}`. Try to avoid using the same "label name" more times.